# Setting Up CiviEvent to Manage Two Side by Side Events with the Option of Registering for Both

Tags: civievent, drupal

What might be the best way to set up CiviEvent that can register attendees for two events, with one that is directly before the other event, as well as having the option where people can register for both at a discount?

I haven't used CiviEvent before, and from reading the documentation wasn't sure of the best approach. I thought there may be three ways of doing it:

1. Set up three distinct events in CiviEvent. One for each individual event and one for both.
2. Set up two individual events where each has an option in the pricing to include the other event.
3. Set up one "parent" event that includes pricing options to go to either both or one of the "child events"

In option 1, having three events may be problamatic as there would be two attendance lists for each event.

It seems that the second option might be easier but then I don't know how it would handle registration for the second event, as the person registering for one event would only appear on that individual event registration list.

For the third option, I'm not sure how the registrations would work for working out who was going to which child event. Would this be using Smart Groups? And I could forsee difficulties setting up automated responses depending on which child event had been selected.

Any guidance much appreciated! (I am using Drupal 7.60 with CiviCRM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Webform CiviCRM module? It will let you add multiple CiviEvents as simple checkboxes, set fees, assign discounts based on conditionals, sign up multiple participants, relate them to each other all on one page.

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried Webform connecting to CiviCRM events. That sounds very promising. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ben - I've added a visual for you :-)

Comment: Thanks! That makes the options really clear :)

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT - that looks good.  With webform getting ever more capable it would be great to have a few in-depth tutorials to create complex real-world webforms like this one. Maybe sometime when you're not busy :-)

Comment: Yes lots of options! And so little time :-) I try to get to webform civicrm SE questions as much as I can. But ok - I promise to try get some complex tutorials together.

Comment: How can I place participants list Side-by-Side like in the picture above please?

Comment: In D7-> you need webform_layout module; in D8 you can use the baked in flexboxes